# Python: How to feed large dataset to Keras Model?

Tags: python, opencv, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Basically I have a training dataset with 100s of thousands of images with labels that can be used to train an ML model.
However (as expected) I can't simply create a numpy array to hold the images as follows:

all_images = np.zeros(shape=(500000, 256, 256, 3), dtype="uint8")

I don't suppose large companies simply have 'huge' ram to use huge datasets for training.

So how can I use the entire data set for training without having to hold the entire thing in memory before calling model.fit()?

Here's the entire loading function if needed:

(details about it below)

```
def load_images(images: list):
# Create empty np.ndarray to hold n images of size 256 x 256 with 3 channels (RGB)
resized_images = np.zeros(shape=(len(images), 256, 256, 3), dtype="uint8")

index = 0
for image in images:
    print(index)

    # Load image with cv2
    img = cv2.imread(images)

    # Resize image to 256 width, 256 height
    img = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(256, 256))

    # Add image to ndarray 'resized_images'
    resized_images[index] = img

    index += 1
return resized_images
```

The objective of this function is to resize the training images and load them into a single numpy array to be passed to the model in model.fit()
Note: I removed some np.transpose() calls to make the code more legible so this might not work if copied and pasted

So far I've tried saving the model and loading it up to continue the training without success (loading model doesn't retain all properties). But if this is the best way feel free to share your method.

Answer (score 1):

Consider of using such wonderful thing as **generator**.

At first I would suggest you to pay attantion on `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` class and its method `flow_from_directory()`.

In case you want to preprocess images in some unusual way I would recommend you to consider creating your own generator by inheriting from the `tf.keras.utils.Sequence` class like this:

`class CustomImageDataGen(tf.keras.utils.Sequence)`

[This article](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) may help.